# Count records by group with 0 number for records out of criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Need a rope ;)) Take a look on example:

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test3](
    [software] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [result] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [computername] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)
```

With data:

```
INSERT INTO test3 VALUES ('Adobe',1,'abc')
INSERT INTO test3 VALUES ('Office',1,'abc')
INSERT INTO test3 VALUES ('Adobe',0,'def')
INSERT INTO test3 VALUES ('Office',1,'def')
```

So after ordinary SELECT we have:

```
software                                           result computername
Office                                             1      abc
Adobe                                              1      abc
Office                                             1      123
Adobe                                              0      123
```

An NOW, my question. I would like to count Software quantity by software group. The "Result" column means: 0 not installed, 1 installed.

To count all installed (result=1) I can do simple:

```
SELECT
    Software
    ,COUNT(*) as Quantity
FROM
    test3
WHERE
    result = 1
GROUP BY
    software
```

BUT if I want to "reverse" the result and count how many computers from table have not software installed  (result = 0) I will not see a results which I needs (for report).

After that:

```
SELECT
    Software
    ,COUNT(*) as Quantity
FROM
    test3
WHERE
    result = 0
GROUP BY
    software
```

I will get:

```
Software                                           Quantity
-------------------------------------------------- -----------
Adobe                                              1
```

Which means: "Only 1 Adobe is missed and rest of software is installed everywhere".

But I need for good look of report something like that:

```
Software                                           Quantity
-------------------------------------------------- -----------
Adobe                                              1
Office                                             0
```

Which means ;) "Only 1 Adobe installation is missed and 0 Office installation is missed."

I'm stuck with that :/ Plz help :)

Comment: You need to store the number of licenses per software, and I recommend doing it in a separate table.

Comment: In normal case,  sure. But that one is just a report from scan logs and not used for any other areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the result check from the WHERE clause to a CASE:

```
SELECT
    Software
,   SUM(case when result = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Missing
FROM     test3
GROUP BY software
```

That way, you will see software which has only successful installations.

Comment: Looks perfect :) I hope the case statement will not affect perfomance too much. Thanks a lot!